# Implement BarChart with series by Date

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have this data stored into database:

[image]

I would like to generate the data into Primefaces bar chart by date:

```
TicketStatusReportObj obj;
List<TicketStatusReportObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
// here we insert days using loop with data from database:
obj = new TicketStatusReportObj(
                    rs.getInt("CNT_STATUS0"),
                    rs.getInt("CNT_STATUS1"),
                    rs.getInt("CNT_STATUS2"),
                    rs.getInt("CNT_STATUS3"),
                    rs.getInt("CNT_STATUS4"),
                    rs.getDate("CREATED")
                );

                list.add(obj);
...

    ChartSeries series;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                series = new ChartSeries();
                TicketStatusReportObj get = list.get(i);
                int in_progress = get.getIn_progress();
                int new_ticket = get.getNew_ticket();
                int closed = get.getClosed();
                int resolved = get.getResolved();
                int rejected = get.getRejected();
                Date date = get.getDate();

                series.setLabel(date.toString());
                series.set(date.toString(), in_progress);
                series.set(date.toString(), new_ticket);
                series.set(date.toString(), closed);
                series.set(date.toString(), resolved);
                series.set(date.toString(), rejected);

                barModel.addSeries(series);
            }
```

But I get this result:

[image]

As you can see I have only one day but it shoud be 4 because I have 4 days into the database table. Wha is the proper way to generate 4 days with 4 series of columns in Primefaces Bar chart?

Comment: In your case i think it is impossible to use BarChart, its better to use Line chart because you have many information in your database, for the XAxis i suggest to use CREATED_DATE, and for the YAaxis use the other informationcnt_statut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
ChartSeries series1 = new ChartSeries();
ChartSeries series2 = new ChartSeries();
ChartSeries series3 = new ChartSeries();
ChartSeries series4 = new ChartSeries();
ChartSeries series1 = new ChartSeries();
series1.setLabel("In Progress");
series2.setLabel("New Ticket");
series3.setLabel("Closed");
series4.setLabel("Resolved");
series5.setLabel("Rejected");

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    TicketStatusReportObj get = list.get(i);
    int in_progress = get.getIn_progress();
    int new_ticket = get.getNew_ticket();
    int closed = get.getClosed();
    int resolved = get.getResolved();
    int rejected = get.getRejected();
    Date date = get.getDate();

    series1.set(date, in_progress);
    series2.set(date, new_ticket);
    series3.set(date, closed);
    series4.set(date, resolved);
    series5.set(date, rejected);
}

barModel.addSeries(series1);
barModel.addSeries(series2);
barModel.addSeries(series3);
barModel.addSeries(series4);
barModel.addSeries(series5);
```

Comment: Please add some text and explanation to the answer.